# Plotting symbols in R as Pie Charts of the Weights

Tags: r, plot, charts

Consider this toy example in R

```
x<-seq(0,1,length.out=10)
y<-sin(x)
plot(x,y)
set.seed(10)
weights <- matrix(runif(30),ncol=3)
weights <- sweep(weights,1,apply(weights,1,sum),"/")
```

where each point has probabilities associated with being in 3 groups. For example, the first observation has

```
     [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
 [1,] 0.2507483 0.32198731 0.4272644
```

0.25 probability of being in group 1, 0.32 of being in group 2 and 0.43 of being in group 3. How can I make a plotting symbol for each point to look like a mini pie chart that will colour the pie chart accordingly? For example, for the first point, the plotting symbol would look like this

```
pie(weights[1,],labels=NA)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `plotrix`:

```
plot(-0.1:1, -0.1:1, "n")
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  floating.pie(x[i], y[i], weights[i,], radius=0.05, col = c("#ffffff", "#d3d3d3", "#add8e6"))
}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Brilliant